# JPanel doesn't show when added to another one

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a problem with the following code.

```
public class Simulation extends Thread{
    private Map map;
    private Camera camera;
    private JPanel container;

    public Simulation(Map map){
        this.map = map;
        camera = new Camera(map);
        container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        container.add(camera);
    }

    public JPanel getSimView(){  //I WANT THIS TO RETURN CONTAINER WITH CAMERA ADDED TO, INSTEAD OF CAMERA ITSELF  
        return camera;                          
    }
```

Class Simulation creates a JPanel when built. Then a JFrame calls getSimView() to get the JPanel.

It works properly if getSimView() returns Camera camera (Camera is subclass of JPanel).

But when i try to return JPanel container with camera added to (as the comment suggests), nothing get shown on the frame.

Comment: For better help sooner please post  a valid [mcve]